Counterexample wanted: Banach space but not BK-space
What is an example of a Banach space that is not a BK-space?
A normed sequence space $X$ (with projections $p_n$) is a BK Space if $X$ is Banach space and for all natural numbers $n$, $p_n(\bar{x}) = x_n$ is continuous, for all $\bar{x}$ in $X$.

You haven't defined $p_n$.

@YCor I believe they are the coordinate projections, since a BK-space is a Banach space whose elements are sequences (plus the continuity condition)

@Maulana Do you want a Banach space that is also a sequence space? Otherwise any Banach space that is not embeddable in a sequence space might count (warning: I'm not a functional analyst!)

It seems that a BK-space $X$ should have a continuous linear inclusion (in particular, injective map) into $\mathbb C^{\mathbb N}$ (with the product topology making it a Fréchet space). This is certainly impossible if the cardinality (or Hamel-dimension) of $X$ is bigger than that of  $\mathbb C^{\mathbb N}$. A concrete example is the Banach space $X$ of all bounded functions from $\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$.

Yes, it is elementary that a Fréchet space $X$ is a BK space if and only if there is a continuous linear injection from $X$  into $\mathbb C^{\mathbb N}$ (with the product topology)  if and only if $X^$ is weak$^$ separable.
